# Cannot connect HTC One X to PC

Tags: usb, htc-one-x

I'm having trouble connecting my HTC One X to my PC. Every time I plug it into a USB port it starts charging and my PC shows "Could not recognize USB device". I'm running Win7 x64. I installed HTC Sync manager and switched the connection option to 'HTC Sync' (also tried 'Drive Storage') and tried enabling USB debugging in developer options as well.

I also tried to connect to my notebook (also Win7 x64) and I got same error.

Answer (score 1):

[The issue was evidently resolved by using a different USB cord](https://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1365).